# VBA Worksheet Function Index-Match throwing up type mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a macro that uses VBA to complete an index-match function. The vba errors out, saying I have a type mismatch, however I use the same variables earlier in the script in a similar way and that runs with no issues. The lookup values are in another sheet called "Items". The code snippet is below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Test_1

Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim r As Range, cell As Range, aCell As Range, LastRow As Range
Dim strSearch As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

With wb
    strSearch = "Column_1"
    i = 0
    Set LastRow = ws4.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    Set aCell = ws4.Rows(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
            ws4.Cells(i, aCell).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(wb.Sheets("Items").Range("D:D"), WorksheetFunction.Match(ws4.Cells(i, aCell), wb.Sheets("Items").Range("A:A")))
        On Error Resume Next
        Next i
        Else: 'Do Nothing
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I think what you want to try is **1.** Change `LastRow As Range` to `LastRow As Long` **2.** Change `Set LastRow = ws4.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)` to `LastRow = ws4.Range("A" & ws4.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row` and then `For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1` would make more sense. Else if you declare it as range and there is "text" in the last cell then `For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1` will fail.

Comment: Also probably `ws4.Cells(i, aCell.Column).Value =...`

Answer (score 0):

### Application.Match feat. IsNumber (IsError)

- This should get you on the right track. Just solve the mystery where you're searching for the value of a cell in one column, returning the associated value of another column, yet using it to overwrite the value in the initial cell which is kind of unusual.

```vb
Sub Test_1()

    Dim ws As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet4") ' ???
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Items")
    
    Dim Header As String: Header = "Column_1"
    Dim hCell As Range: Set hCell = dws.Rows(1).Find(Header, _
        dws.Rows(1).Cells(dws.Rows(1).Cells.Count), xlFormulas, xlWhole)
    
    If Not hCell Is Nothing Then
        
        Dim hCol As Long: hCol = hCell.Column
        Dim LastRow As Long
        Set LastRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = sws.Range("A:A") ' Lookup Range
        Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("D:D") ' Source Range
        
        Dim cIndex As Long
        Dim i As Long
        
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            ' dws.Cells(i, col) ??? - You usually don't overwrite the value...
            cIndex = Application.Match(dws.Cells(i, col).Value, lrg, 0)
            If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
                ' ... that you were searching for ???
                dws.Cells(i, col).Value = srg.Cells(cIndex).Value
            End If
        Next i
    
    End If

End Sub
```